# Set ForeColor won't execute in Exit event

Tags: excel, vba, events, userform

I have a small user form with two scrollbars which I use for changing a cell value. They are in the tab order and I want to show when they have the focus. Therefore I change their forecolor on *Enter* and change it back on *Exit*. All works fine except that the color doesn't change back. It changes on Enter but not on Exit. This is the code for one of them.

```
Private Sub ScbWeek_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ScbWeek.ForeColor = vbWhite
End Sub
```

I put a breakpoint on the line to see if the event fired. It did, and when I continued the code after stopping the colour was correctly changed. I added a test:-

```
Debug.Print "ScbWeek.ForeColor = vbWhite = "; ScbWeek.ForeColor = vbWhite
```

The test returns True at runtime but the forecolor will continue to be yellow. White is the original colour which was changed to vbYellow on Enter. The other scrollbar changes from black to vbRed and refuses to go back to vbBlack in the same manner. I tested the exit event by both tabbing to the next control (forward and backward) and clicking on another control.

The form is a small one, with just 1 textbox, 2 buttons, the 2 scrollbars and a few labels. It is part of a fairly large project. *ScreenUpdating* is not suppressed while this form is shown and, anyway, changes are displayed as described above.

What can I do?

Comment: Tried `Me.Repaint` ?

Comment: `ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean` is  the content that closes the user form.

Comment: @Tim Williams Bravo! That did the trick. Please post it as an answer so that I can select it. Had I ever come across `Repaint` before I would surely have tried it before asking. Haha - the value of experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
Me.Repaint
```

which should refresh the form's UI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/repaint-method

Answer (score 0):

Make this change and test it. This will be the event when the user form is closed.

```
Private Sub ScbWeek_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox "userform closed!!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. There is no question of closing the form. The intention is to set the ForeColor.

Comment: @Variatus,  What I'm saying is that this event doesn't suit what you're trying to do.